# Insert specific information to a posts of a predefined category

Tags: posts, plugin-development, javascript

I want to show some detail information on specific (for e.g. category=3) posts.

Therefore I use the following coding:

```
function postinfo_head() {

    global $post;
    $script = <<< EOF
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.post-info').hide();
        $('.open-post-info').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            $('.post-info-' + id).slideToggle("medium", function() {
                $(this).prev().toggleClass("toggled");
            }); 

            return false;
        });
    });       
</script>
EOF;
    echo $script;
    postinfo();
}
add_action('wp_head', 'postinfo_head');

function postinfo() {
    global $post;
    echo '<p class="open-post-info" id="'. $post->post_name .'">Details</p>';
    echo '<div class="post-info post-info-'. $post->post_name .'">';
    echo '<ul>';
    ... some detail fields
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Unfortunately the output is shown somewhere else (on top-left of the site - over the header img). **How is it possible to show this coding below the header of a post?**

I would reluctantly edit the template, if there is an other option of getting this to work.

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't inject `postinfo()` in the `<head>` section (that's what happens when you use the `wp_head` hook).

If you do not want to edit templates, I'd suggest you use the `wp_footer` hook instead, and [append](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) the postinfo to your header div with jQuery, e.g.:

`$('.post-info').appendTo('#header');`